# Gitlab CI CD not building docker image in my subfolders

Tags: .net, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have simple .net application and trying to create pipe line but am getting below error when trying to build the image
"invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase"

[Error when running the pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6teg9.png)
**.gitlab-ci.yml file** :

```
default:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0  
stages:
  - build
services:
  - docker:dind
docker-build: 
  image: 
    # name: docker/compose:latest
    name: docker:latest
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    #- docker-compose version
  script:
    - echo "docker build started"  
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY/project/dncd.project.portal/
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/project/dncd.project.portal/ . 
    #- docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    #- docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/services/api/dncd.service.api/" . 
    #- docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    #- docker-compose build
    - echo "build completed"
```

**Gitlab runner - config.toml:**

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "win11"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "5eNzn9o3FMvuUxUmgxDh"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "aspnet:3.1"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

**project structure**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0B9u.png)

Docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Project/DNCD.Project.Portal/DNCD.Project.Portal.csproj", "Project/DNCD.Project.Portal/"]
COPY ["Services/API/DNCD.Services.API.Proxy/DNCD.Services.API.Proxy.csproj", "Services/API/DNCD.Services.API.Proxy/"]
COPY ["Common/DNCD.Common.Base/DNCD.Common.Base.csproj", "Common/DNCD.Common.Base/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Project/DNCD.Project.Portal/DNCD.Project.Portal.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project/DNCD.Project.Portal"
RUN dotnet build "DNCD.Project.Portal.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DNCD.Project.Portal.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DNCD.Project.Portal.dll"]
```

Comment: Could you please verify if the code you've shared is actually the one that ran in that linked pipeline screenshot? The `docker build` line seems to be different ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure in your `gitlab-ci.yml` you fixed

`- docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/project/dncd.project.portal/Dockerfile .` ? Seems like you commited the instruction with the typo.

It should be `- docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/project/dncd.project.portal/ .`

Comment: I tried both but same error:$ echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/project/dncd.project.portal/
registry.gitlab.com/venkat-test-group/docker.dotnetcoredemo/project/dncd.project.portal/
$ docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/project/dncd.project.portal/ .
invalid argument "registry.gitlab.com/venkat-test-group/docker.dotnetcoredemo/project/dncd.project.portal/" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.